# Can I use routes in access_control security configuration?

Tags: symfony

Can I use routes in access_control security configuration?
There is no any information about using routes in security configuration.
I don't want to support two similar definitions of URL paths in routing.yml and security.yml. I just want to define a new route and provide its name to the security  access_control section.
Is it possible?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with that route?

Comment: I want to store URL generation information only in routing config and use it in firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this.

The specified `path` is directly passed as the `RequestMatcher`'s `$path` argument.

The access map entries are registed into the access map here:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/DependencyInjection/SecurityExtension.php#L165-187

Using the request matchers created using this method:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/DependencyInjection/SecurityExtension.php#L539-561

And if you take a look at the `RequestMatcher`'s code, you see it's not coupled to any routing system:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/RequestMatcher.php

Comment: actually have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17661249/symfony2-access-control-with-routes