# Symfony2 access control with routes

Tags: symfony, access-control

I want to limit access to certain routes (not paths) in the `access_control` tag in `security.yml`, but I found nothing in the cookbook or book that shows me how to.
Does anyone else know?

Comment: Really, the section is about Authorization at all, but there's no info to my specific question.

Comment: Authorization is all about `access_control`. If the path is not fain grained enough [secure it by controller](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#securing-a-controller)

Comment: But there'is no answer for my question, is there? You should read the (actually short) question before being impudent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in many ways. For example by implementing own [Security voter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html) that will check matched route