# How to make custom voter call on every request in symfony2

Tags: symfony, authorization

I read this question:[Symfony2 access control with routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17661249/symfony2-access-control-with-routes)
 so
I've created a custom voter according to the instructions at http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html . 
this is my service definition for the voter

```
xml_menu:
    class: "%xml_menu.v1.class%"
    arguments: [""]

route_voter:
    class: "%route_voter.class%"
    arguments: [@request_stack, @xml_menu ]
    public: false
    tags:
        - { name: security.voter }
```

and this is my firewall configuration for it:

```
    test_secured_area:
        pattern: ^/test/
        form_login:
            check_path: _demo_security_check
            login_path: _demo_login
        logout:
            path:   _demo_logout
            target: _demo

access_control:
```

I am intentionally using the demo login paths and left the access_control empty.
I've manually tested the 'route_voter' service and know that it works.However it's load method is not called automatically on any request.is this behaviour supposed to be and I have to call the `isGranted()` method of the security context every time for example at the beginning of my controllers or am I doing something wrong?
If this is the way it's supposed to work how can I force the voter to be called on every request.

what I'm trying to achive here is behaviour similar to access_control, if the user has permission to access the route, the voter returns `VoterInterface::ACCESS_GRANTED`, else, it returns `VoterInterface::ACCESS_DENIED`.and I want access control restrictions to be based on that.
what currently happens is I get redirected to the login page every time I try to access /test/foo, and when I login I'm redirected to hostname/ . then everytime I try to access /test/foo I'm redirected to the demo login page.however when I access the demo secured area it shows that I'm authenticated.so do I have to activate something for the /test/* paths for symfony to read the session and authenticate me so I'm not redirected back to the login page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the check path.as it states in http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html the authentication of the login form is done for the **context** of the firewall that the **check_path** route is under.so the authentication takes place for the demo firewall rather than the one I created.So to fix it I did two things

1. I created a new route for the check_path
2. I substituted that route in the login form template in form action

An alternative solution was to share their firewall context by giving them the same name.