# Symfony2 Routes only for sub-requests

Tags: symfony

I am creating an advanced app that uses websocket instead of ajax for dynamic interaction. My WebSocket messages are handled like HTTP Requests, they contain a json-encoded array of path and parameters, which will be converted to a Request. Now the HttpKernel handles this request like every other HTTP request (as sub-request). The only problem is, that the routes for websocket messages are public avaible.
Has anyone an idea how to allow only internal access for a route in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131923/can-i-use-routes-in-access-control-security-configuration) explains why the firewall configuration can't be used to block routes by name as it uses the `RequestMatcher` which allows only path regexes and not route names.